# How would you label an aspectual suffix that indicates that an action has stopped or become static?

Tags: aspect, descriptive-linguistics, tense-aspect-mood

This suffix seems to behave as the opposite of an inceptive suffix (which indicates that an action has begun).

3SUBJ-go-INCEPTIVE `he started to go'

3SUBJ-go-??? `he stopped'

Comment: Probably _cessative_. You find a Latin verb with the right sense and make a technical word out of it.